# Translate MySQL group by date and select count query to Laravel Eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

How can I translate the following query to [Laravel Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent)?

```
SELECT count(invoices.invoice_id), DATE(created_at) FROM automotive.invoices
where DATE(created_at) >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -10 DAY)
GROUP BY DATE(created_at);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this Eloquent statement:

```php
Invoice::whereDate('created_at', '>=' \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDays(10))
    ->selectRaw("DATE(i.created_at) dt, COUNT(i.invoice_id) cnt")
    ->groupBy('dt')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Incidentally, appropriately indexed, the following would be more efficient:

```
SELECT DATE(i.created_at) dt 
     , COUNT(i.invoice_id)
  FROM invoices i
 WHERE i.created_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 10 DAY
 GROUP 
    BY DATE(i.created_at);
```

Comment: I would close this question as a duplicate if I had your gold badge

Comment: @Saly3301 You still have a vote

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to the Eloquent documentation on the official [Laravel website](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent).

Assuming you don't want to use *RAW statements*, you could try something like:

```php
$datecompare = Carbon::now()->subDays(10)->toDateTimeString();
$data = Invoice::where('created_at', '<', $datecompare)->get();
```

Note that I separated the query in two lines for more clarity.

Then, you could get the count using

```php
$data->count();
```

Don't forger to add this at the top of your controller:

```php
use Carbon\Carbon; // In your controller;
```

Comment: I forgot to specify that I want all in one line instead of get the data then use method on collection. But thanks anyway, ako answer got what I need

Comment: Why backslash in `Carbon\Carbon`? It looks Windows'y.